# RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with my `RelativeLayout`.

I placed 6 `Views` next to each other and it works.

The problem i have are the `EditTexts`. When i set their width to `wrap_content` they are too small.

When i set them to `match_parent` they take the whole width (they are overlaying the other `Views`) instead of adjusting to the edges of the `Views` next to them.

So my question is how can i make them fit without giving them static widths?

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="text 1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et1"
        android:text="text 2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et2"
        android:text="text 3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One thing you can do is wrap them in `LinearLayouts` and then set their width to `match_parent`. That way, regardless of how much text they contain, they will always have the same width. You then just need to balance the widths of the `LinearLayouts` with `weight`. You'll also need to set the `EditTexts` to allow the text to scroll.

Comment: You mean putting each view in it's own LinearLayout? :D I understand it works (i also did that before), but it takes lots of performance. I actually want to use a more elegant way to achieve that.

Comment: *"You mean putting each view in it's own LinearLayout?"* Yes. What do you mean *"takes a lot of performance"*? Do mean it's slow? If so are you testing on an emulator (v. slow) or real device? Agreed, nesting layouts too deeply is not a great way to do things but I have some which go 2 or 3 layers with no perceptible screen lag on real devices. Sure it may not be elegant but if it works to get my layouts exactly how I want them (including adjusting accurately on different screen dpi/size) I'm happy to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Relative Layout you need either a satisfaying wrapcontent or static dimensions.
If I understand well, you want the edit text to fill what is left of the screen's width.
You would have to use a LinearLayout and the `android:layout_weight` property - [you can find an example here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation:"horizontal">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 1" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 3" />

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "If I understand well, you want the edit text to fill what is left of the screen's width." Yes, that's exactly what i want. Like i said, i already tried it with LinearLayout, but the edittexts kept stretching when typing and the right edges were reached. Is there a way to prevent them from stretching if you type something?

Comment: Sorry Charles, i didn't read well. I see you didn't give a layout_weight to each view, only to two of them. I didn't know that's possible. The edittexts now fit perfect to the layout, but there's still the problem that they push the other views offscreen when typing.

Comment: The code i provided does not have them running over edges when empty or when typed in. Please try the code and let me know what happens.

Comment: You are both right actually. This is the solution: Only give layout_weight to the edit texts and set their width to "match_parent". This makes them perfectly fit to the rest of the layout and prevents them from stretching when typing.

Comment: So when you say "So my question is how can i make them fit without giving them static widths?" You meant you only wanted to know apply static widths to the `EditText`? Because you are still applying static widths to the other `Views` with this solution and static widths are going to hurt you on different size screens.

Comment: Strange, I didn't notice a different behaviour with android_width="match_parent" in my case, I may be missing something. Good luck for your app!

Comment: Charles, you are right. 0dp is better for performance than match_parent. All the credit goes to you. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code.

If you are wanting the size of the boxes to be a little different you will need to apply static sizes or play with the weights a little bit to get the right space you want.

*However, i would suggest actually changing the layout a little bit. Having them all on the same line seems somewhat messy. Unless this is for landscape mode. Then it might be ok.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text 1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text 2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text 3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Resulting picture of layout:

[image]

Comment: I already tried LinearLayout with layoutweights. There's the same problem that i had with TableLayouts. When typing and the right edges of the edittexts are reached, they keep stretching and push the other views offscreen.

Comment: Try this and let me how it goes. Copy and paste it into your layout file. This worked for me and should work for you. I posted a screen shot of the resulting layout.

Comment: Answers are sorted by a user. They may not always appear in the same order for everyone. You will just need to tell people to look at a particular solution.